# Appending dynamically generated html using jQuery does not play well with Fancybox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, append, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox (http://fancybox.net) to pop open an iFrame.  In order to do so, I create a link with a class set to "item_pop" as so:

```
<div id="events">
    <a href="http://www.example.com" class="item_pop">My Link</a>
</div>
```

I then have some JavaScript in the footer that supports this:

```
jQuery(".item_pop").fancybox({
        'width'             : 900,
        'height'            : 500,
        'autoDimensions'    : true,
        'autoScale'         : true,
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'titleShow'         : false,
        'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
        'centerOnScroll'    : true,
        'type'              : 'iframe'
});
```

Ok, so this all works swimmingly.  The problem is that I use jQuery to create additional links like this on the fly as so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        update_seconds = 20;
        update_duration = update_seconds * 1000;

        window.setInterval(reload_events, update_duration);
});

function reload_events()
{       
        jQuery.post("http://www.example.com", {type:'any'}, function(data){
            var events = eval(data);
            var html = '';

            for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++){
                var evt = events[i];

                html += '<a href="http://www.example.com" class="item_pop">My Link</a>';
            }

            jQuery('#events').children().remove();
            jQuery('#events').append(html);
        });
}
```

This actually displays the links to screen, but when you click on them they don't pop up the iFrame.  Instead they open the intended page as a new page, rather than as an iFrame inside the existing page.

Any ideas?  Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what's happening is that `jQuery(".item_pop")` finds elements matching the selector *at that time* and binds to those.  Since you're creating new elements later, you need to bindto them.

After this call:

```
jQuery('#events').append(html);
```

You need to run the `.fancybox()` call again, on this set of new elements:

```
jQuery("#events .item_pop").fancybox({ ... });
```

---

Or alternatively (and less efficient) you can use the [`.livequery()` plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery), like this:

```
jQuery(".item_pop").livequery(function() {
  jQuery(this).fancybox({
    'width'             : 900,
    'height'            : 500,
    'autoDimensions'    : true,
    'autoScale'         : true,
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'titleShow'         : false,
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'centerOnScroll'    : true,
    'type'              : 'iframe'
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I used your suggestion to run the Fancybox call again after the HTML was output to screen and it worked a treat.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem as i see it is that fancybox doesn't know anything about these additional links, as the JavaScript is only interpreted as the page loads.  You need to use jQuerys [.Live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/fancybox) so that  fancybox will be aware of any dynamically created content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Fancybox to be worked with dynamic controls you should change in JQuery file of Fancybox.

This is what my jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js looks like
at around line 787:

```
$.fn.fancybox = function(options) {

   $(this)
.die('click.fb').live('click.fb', function(e) {

   $(this).data('fancybox', $.extend({}, options, ($.metadata ? $(this).metadata() :
{})))


   e.preventDefault();
```

after this code is same in the file.

once you change in the Fancybox JQuery file you will not need to change your code.