# Apply jquery fancybox to elements loaded via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, fancybox

I am loading a bunch of data and adding it to a div.  However, some of the items in the data are links that need to be used with fancybox.  I am using fancybox 1.3.4.  I've tried a few solutions such as $fancybox.init(); and $(document).ajaxStop(); and none have worked.  Below is my code:

```
$.post('/ajax/ajax-page.php', $('#filter-results').serialize(), function(boardData){
    leaderboard.html(boardData);
    upper_top_title.text(sport_skill_level+" "+sport_grad_year);
    lower_top_title.text(sport_type+" Leaderboard");
    Cufon.replace('.t');

    // reload scripts necessary for data, fancybox and font
    $.getScript("/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js", function(){
        $.fancybox.init();
            $("a.video").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
                'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
                'speedIn'       :   400, 
                'speedOut'      :   200, 
                'overlayShow'   :   true, 
                'showCloseButton' : true, 
                'width'         : 670, 
                'height'        : 385, 
                'titleShow'     : false, 
                'type'          : 'iframe'
            });
        });

        $.getScript("/js/init.js",  function() {
            loading.hide().parent().find('#leaderboard').show();
            filter_res_btn.removeClass("disabled_btn").removeAttr('disabled');
            $('.ui-selectmenu').removeClass("disabled_btn").removeAttr('disabled');
        });

    });
```

Although the fancybox code is now inside the $.getScript(), it wasn't there before, I just tried that before posting this.  All i get now when I click the links is an error saying:

> t is undefined     (19 out of range 4)

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Is `div#leaderboard` the container where you are loading the data? like `<div id="leaderboard"><a class="video" ....`?

Comment: @JFK, Yeah it is, I'm loading the data that is a table so it looks like
<div id="leaderboard">
<table>
<tr><td><a class="video">asdsad</a></td></tr>
</table>
</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fancybox 1.3.4 doesn't support dynamically added elements, however you could use jQuery (v1.7.x) API [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to bind those new elements to fancybox. [Check this post for "how to"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084293/1055987).

Comment: That did it for me!  Thanks so much! This has been so aggravating!