# jQuery with Fancybox on dynamically created elements. Only works on the second click and never on the first

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using Fancybox together with a slideshow. I have a slideshow that "dynamically" loads items from the database.

```
<div id="#slideshow">
    <div id="#slide-description">
        <a href="http://localhost/test.php">Fancybox here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Everything inside the `#slideshow` div is dynamically generated by jQuery.

My javascript looks like this:

```
$("#slide-description").on('click', 'a', function() {
    console.log('triggerd click!');
    $(this).fancybox({
        type: "ajax",
        ajax: {
            dataFilter: function(data) {                
                return $(data).find("#portfolio-info");
            }
        },
        onComplete: function(){
            console.log('done.');
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

My problem is that it works ONLY works when I click on the link twice - `<a href="http://localhost/test.php">Fancybox here</a>`.

When I click the link the first time, `triggered click!` is logged in the console but no `GET` request. Then when I click it the second time, it works!

Console:

```
triggerd click! /* 1st click */
GET http://localhost:8888/raydar/portfolio/frucor-1/ 200 OK /* 2nd click */
triggerd click! /* 2nd click */
done. /* 2nd click */
```

Any reply would be greatly appreciated as I have already spent a few hours on this.

Comment: If everything inside of #slideshow is dynamically generated, that means you are destroying and recreating #slide-description, too. So you don't want to bind your listener to that. Why not bind the listener to #slideshow itself?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg. I have tried `$("#slideshow").on('click', 'a', function() {...` and `$("#slideshow a").on('click', function() {...` and both do not work. The problem when I do this is that the `href` in the `<a>` tag is followed/executed and it goes to the link instead of loading it in the Fancybox. Your thoughts?

Comment: If working with fancybox v1.3.4 and dynamically added elements, you could also check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9084293/1055987

Answer (score 1):

As a reply to the question in the comment section:

If the problem is that the link is being followed, you need to prevent default behaviour:

```
$("#slideshow").on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  /* the rest */
});
```

Note that you can also use `return false;` at the end of the function, which prevents default behaviour and stops propagation, if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks again. I have placed the "bind" on `$("#slideshow").on('click',...` as you have specified but still having a problem - it only works on the second click but not on the first one.

Comment: I'm flying a bit blind without actually having Fancybox onhand. Does the $(this) reference fit? In the context, $(this) is a jQuery-wrapped anchor. Is that the right thing to be fancybox'd? Also part of flying blind: what exactly does `data` contain? Can it be jQuery wrapped?

Comment: Thanks so much Greg. Due to your comments and your answer, I am able to properly "fetch" the URL on the first click. I will be posting an answer shortly for the others. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Greg Pettit's comments and answer gave me an idea of how to do it in another way. I re-read Fancybox's docs and found out that for Ajax requests, there is a `url` option.

From http://fancybox.net/blog:

```
$("#login_form").bind("submit", function() {

    if ($("#login_name").val().length < 1 || $("#login_pass").val().length < 1) {
        $("#login_error").show();
        $.fancybox.resize();
        return false;
    }

    $.fancybox.showActivity();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache   : false,
        url     : "/data/login.php", /*i'm talking about this*/
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

With that, I came up with this:

```
$("#slideshow").on('click','#slide-description a', function() {
    $.fancybox({
        type: "ajax",
        ajax: {
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).attr("href"), /*we get the URL from "#slide-description a" and load it*/
            dataFilter: function(data) {                
                return $(data).find("#portfolio-info");
            }
        },
        onComplete: function(){
            console.log('done.');
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Right on! Glad I could help in some small way.