# Fancybox image gallery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to do a Fancybox image gallery. I have a function that takes a list of image URLs and appends them to the DOM like so

```
function handleImageURLs(imageURLs) {
  var appendString = "";

  //Create an <a> tag for each image URL
  for(var i = imageURLs.length - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
    appendString += "<a href='"+ imageURLs[i] +"' rel='img_preview'><img src='"+ imageURLs[i] +" />'</a>";
  }

  //Add the <a> tags containing images to the <body> element
  $("body").append(appendString);

  //Select the image <a> tags and call Fancybox
  $("a[rel='img_preview']").fancybox({
    onCleanup: function() {
      //do cleanup stuff, remove images, etc.
    }
  });
}
```

Everything works fine. The `<a>` tags get added to the DOM. But Fancybox doesn't open at all. And doesn't throw any errors. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you certain your `$("a[rel='img_preview']")` selector contains elements (i.e. isn't empty)?

Comment: Yes. Definitely not empty. I've also tried giving my `<a>` tags the same class and selecting them using the class (as shown on the Fancybox [howto](http://fancybox.net/howto) page)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11401917/1055987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081571/how-to-bind-fancybox-to-dynamic-added-element/9084293#9084293) and triggered a `click` event on the image that I wanted to display.