# Jquery Fancy Box loading issue AJAX response

Tags: jquery, fancybox

As of my below code, it does not load the fancy box after the AJAX response when clicking the link.

Id of the `<a>` tag is generated dynamically.

But when i click the same link in the second time it loads but AJAX function also is getting recalled.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

   $(".cont").live('click',function(e)
    {
        //Cancel the default action (navigation) of the click.
        e.preventDefault();

        var contentId = $(this).attr('id');


        $('#apps').load('/app/get-app-details', function(){
            $("#"+contentId).fancybox();
        });

    });


  });

<a class="cont" href="#device_detection" id="apps_<?= $regUsers->id; ?>"> Click to view apps</a>
```

Please provide me a solution.

Comment: Is this need to be down voted. It may have the duplicated Subject. But the content is different. I already checked the questions similar to this and those are not my question.

Comment: Fancybox v1.3.4 doesn't support dynamically added elements. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9084293/1055987 for a workaround.

Comment: New version is a paid one. right?

Comment: v2.x has a pricing license scheme for commercial use

Answer (score 0):

This is working.May be some one else have useful

```
  $(".cont").live("click",function() {

      link=($(this).attr('href'));



            $.fancybox({
            'width'                : '1000',
            'href'                 : link,
            'height'            : '750',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'        : 'none',
            'transitionOut'        : 'none',
            'type'                : 'iframe'
            }); 





      return false; // don't follow the link!
           });
```

Live is deprecated with latest jquery .so you can use

```
$("body").on("click",".cont",function() {

      link=($(this).attr('href'));



            $.fancybox({
            'width'                : '1000',
            'href'                 : link,
            'height'            : '750',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'        : 'none',
            'transitionOut'        : 'none',
            'type'                : 'iframe'
            }); 





      event.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link!
           });
```