# Fancybox, simple thumbnail gallery, and applying lightbox link and new image src on click

Tags: jquery, fancybox, thumbnails, image-gallery

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around how to apply Fancybox to a thumbnail gallery so that when the main image is loaded, it can be clicked to open up a larger version of that image.

I don't know, words escape me. Here is a concrete example: http://bloc-nc.com/projects/gateway.html

If you switch from one thumb to the other, the large image opened is still of the first image and not of the new one.

My code looks like this:

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){                
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
});

$('#largeImage').wrap(function() {
    return '<a class="zoom" href="' + $(this).attr('src').replace('large','zoom') + '" />'});
```

What am I missing? Thank you very, very much in advance!!

Comment: Doesn't the `button helper` address your issue? Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples ---> Extended functionality ---> Button helper

Comment: My bad, I just saw your link and realized you are using fancybox v1.3.4 ... disregard my comment.

Comment: `be clicked to open up a larger version of that image` : do you mean outside fancybox (another browser tab for instance)?

Comment: Nope, inside fancybox. I basically have three different images. The thumb, the main image, and the zoom image. I want to make it so that when you click on a thumbnail, the main image changes respectively, and then when you click on the main image, the zoom version of the image pops up in the fancybox. They're three files in three different sizes. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a different approach? ... so instead of using `.replace()` we'll use `.each()` to bind the `click` event to each thumbnail and replace the *large* image in the `#panel` container :

```
$("#thumbs img").each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var imgPanel = '<a href="http://bloc-nc.com/projects/images/gateway/gateway' + (i + 1) + '_zoom.png" class="zoom" tabindex="' + (i + 1) + '"><img src="http://bloc-nc.com/projects/images/gateway/gateway' + (i + 1) + '_large.png" id="largeImage" /></a>';
        $("#panel").html(imgPanel);
    }); // click
}); // each
```

**Notice** that we are building the variable `imgPanel` that actually replaces the number `(i+1)` of both the *zoom* image (in the `href` of the `<a>` tag) AND the the *large* image (in the `src` of the `<img>` tag)

Then, the content of the `<div id="panel">` container is replaced depending on the thumbnail clicked.

On the other hand, it would be easy to use `$("a.zoom").fancybox();` to bind fancybox to the link with `class="zoom"`, however you are using fancybox v1.3.4 and that version **doesn't support dynamically added elements**, **[see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9081571/1055987)** for reference.

So we would need to initialize fancybox in a different way to support those dynamic elements (every time we replace the *large* image, we change the link `.zoom` dynamically)

This script should do the trick :

```
$(".gallery").delegate("#panel", "focusin", function () {
    $("a.zoom").fancybox();
});
```

Notice that we are using `.delegate()` instead of `.on()` as in the post of reference because you are using a jQuery version lower than v1.7.x

So, altogether

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#thumbs img").each(function (i) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var imgPanel = '<a href="http://bloc-nc.com/projects/images/gateway/gateway' + (i + 1) + '_zoom.png" class="zoom" tabindex="' + (i + 1) + '"><img src="http://bloc-nc.com/projects/images/gateway/gateway' + (i + 1) + '_large.png" id="largeImage" /></a>';
            $("#panel").html(imgPanel);
        }); // click
    }); // each
    // initialize fancybox for dynamically added elements
    $(".gallery").delegate("#panel", "focusin", function () {
        $("a.zoom").fancybox();
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DeE4X/)**

Comment: This is great, JFK, thank you! I'm going to experiment with getting the lightbox initialized before the user clicks in the #panel, but other than that, this kind of new thinking is exactly what I needed. Seriously, thank you so much!