# jquery not loading gallery jquery.infinitegallery.js wordpress lightbox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, incompatibility

I bought this premium theme from Themeforest and when I wen'tback for support the Author and Theme had dissapeared.
Please help!

I bought this premium theme from Themeforest and when I wen't back for support the Author and Theme had dissapeared. I had already launched my site and it was too late to turn back. At first everything worked perfectly but somehow my site started having compatability issues with certain web browsers and now I'm stuck with no support. Please help me....

Compatability issues with Firefox and Chrome using Wordpress, jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js, and jquery.infinitegallery.js.

First I'll give an example of the issue I am having. Go to my website http://www.viintage.com and then click on any of the first images that are loaded into the home page.

Image is loading via jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js

Image is loaded and displayed. Now either click the X or press escape key to close fancybox overlay.

Everything seems to be working properly right? Well after you scroll down and the next page of images autoloads via the infinitegallery.js - everything gets broken.

Notice the loading gif indicating that the next page of images are loading.

There are over 100 images in the gallery on the home page of my site but only the first 2 pages of images load. PLUS, now if you scroll back up to the first images that were loaded and click on one of them... Nothing happens. I assume that Ajax is no longer being called on the page due to some script issue??? The only way to see a larger version of the image now is to right click and open in a new tab. Which is not very intuitive and not how the wordpress theme was designed, not to mention that none of the other 100 plus images are loaded at all. However, if you are using Safari or IE web browsers then you'll have no issues at all. Only in Firefox and Chrome am I seeing these issues, and unfortunately over 50% of my visitors are using Firefox and Chrome as their web browsers.

Please help me to solve this problem.

I have tried downgrading Wordpress, disabling all of my plugins, I've been digging through forums for over 3 months without any luck. If my Google SEO wasn't so good then I would probably just start from scratch but I'm getting really good SERP's and I don't want to risk getting ditched by Google if I were to have issues with missing links on my site. I've also uploaded over 35,000 images and it would be a nightmare to have to start uploading from scratch again. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is because fancybox v1.3.4 doesn't support dynamically added elements. Here is a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/a/9084293/1055987

Comment: @JFK Thanks for the quick reply. I read the workaround and I'm excited to give it a try. I'm definitely not a skilled coder, so do you have any advice that will help me make this happen inside the confines of wordpress? I don't have clue where I would even start to find the

`$("#container").on("focusin", function(){
 $("a.ajaxFancyBox").fancybox({
  // fancybox API options here
  'padding': 0
 }); // fancybox
}); // on
`

Comment: `$("#container").on("focusin" ...etc` doesn't exist in your code, is just an example of how your structure should look like but you have to create your own custom script. For WordPress, you may need to modify your theme's (or child theme) `head.php` file and insert it there after you loaded the fancybox files