# Using fancybox after a postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I started to use fancybox plugin yesterday during my web developing in C# asp.net, and I succeeded to use it for showing hidden panels, images and etc.

But today I wanted to use it for a different case, after a postback.

I have some link buttons which are created dynamically on page load. Each button click changes hidden panel's content - a label's text, for instance. I want to show the changed panel in a fancybox, but I really have no idea how.

I just wanted to say that I searched a solution for hours and I didn't find a solution that matches to my problem.

May I do something wrong?
I will be happy to learn.

Thanks.

**Edit**

My html document includes:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">   
</asp:Panel>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="data">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Panel1 is gonna be the dynamic buttons' parent.
data div is the div which its content has to be shown in the fancybox.

The code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        LinkButton but = new LinkButton() { ID = "LinkButton" + i.ToString(), Text=i.ToString(), CssClass="fancybutton" };
        but.Font.Size = 100;
        but.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(but);
    }
}

protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = (sender as LinkButton).ID;
    Label1.Text = id;

    Response.Write(Label1.Text); // test in purpose to see the label text's change
}
```

my jquery:

```
        $(".fancybutton").click(function () {
            $.fancybox({
                'type': 'inline',
                'content': '#data'
            });
        });
```

it looks like that the fancybox appears for a second, but because of the postback the page is refreshed the fancybox disappears.

Comment: what version of fancybox? if v1.3.4, that version doesn't support dynamically added elements so check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9084293/1055987 .... if using v2.x and still not working, then post the code you are using or a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: but server controls are different I guess (tell me if I wrong). I will try to make myself more clear - link buttons have click event in the code behind. I have 4 link buttons, which each link button changes a label text in code behind. My question is how do I make the change in server and then call the fancybox to pop up.

Comment: Don't know, we need to see your rendered html and the jQuery code that binds events to those html elements before we can make any assumption

Comment: eh I use some objects that I made and etc, but I will try to make a demo in a minute

Comment: my question is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :
As you said that your fancy box shows up for a second or so and then due to page refresh it hides..

```
$(".fancybutton").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // If this does not work also try "event.stopPropagation();"
    $.fancybox({
        'type': 'inline',
        'content': '#data'
    });
});
```

I hope this will work for you as I have answered to what I have understood from your question. Let me know if this works for you. Cheers.

Comment: My problem is that I can mix the data changing and the fancybox. I've tried to do it before..

Comment: Boss. Your question is not clear. This is the main reason why other programmers did not comment anything. Please try to make yourself a little bit more clear or please create a fiddle for your issue which will help us understand you better.

Comment: The fancybox appears but the label text isn't changed - it remains "Label" every click. I guess that the post back doesn't occurs.
I tried the second option you suggested me and the post back occurs but the fancybox doesn't appear, although not for a second.

Comment: I also used this code as even I was also stuck in something similar.