# Fancybox Observer across multiple links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

If I have this markup:

```
<a href="#" data-fancybox-content="<p>Content 1</p>"> Click Here for Content 1</a>
<a href="#" data-fancybox-content="<p>Content 2</p>"> Click Here for Content 2</a>
<a href="#" data-fancybox-content="<p>Content 3</p>"> Click Here for Content 3</a>
<a href="#" data-fancybox-content="<p>Content 4</p>"> Click Here for Content 4</a>
```

And I want to set up my fancybox observer for each of those, but I want the `content` of the popup set to each link's data-fancybox-content, is there a way to do that in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `.each()` method but use the regular fancybox initialization script to bind your selectors (or elements) to fancybox, so

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#" data-content="<p>Content 1</p>"> Click Here for Content 1</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#" data-content="<p>Content 2</p>"> Click Here for Content 2</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#" data-content="<p>Content 3</p>"> Click Here for Content 3</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#" data-content="<p>Content 4</p>"> Click Here for Content 4</a>
```

**Notice** that is not a good idea to bind javascript *events* to global elements (HTML tags) but use specificity (CSS selectors) instead, so we added the *class* `fancybox` to the elements we want to bind to fancybox.

Also notice that we only used `data-content` instead of `data-fancybox-content` attributes (`data-fancybox-{something}` is an special attribute that has no value for `content`)

Then you can set the `content` dynamically using the `beforeLoad` callback like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function () {
            this.content = $(this.element).data("content");
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/usm663s2/)**

PS. you could even set a fancybox gallery by setting a `rel` or `data-fancybox-group` attribute to your elements. You wouldn't be able to do that with the `.each()` method.

Comment: is there a way to do this for dynamically generated links? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534759/create-a-simple-modal-pop-up-window-in-xslt

Comment: @ankk : this is for fancybox v2.x which supports dynamically added elements. For fancybox v1.3.x check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9084293/1055987

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, here's how I did it:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).fancybox({
        content: $(this).attr('data-fancybox-content'),
    });
});
```