# Loading Easy Fancybox with Ajax Load More + Next Page Add on

Tags: ajax, dynamic, lightbox, infinite-scroll

I have Easy Fancybox with Ajax Load More + Next Page Addon (Same company). My issue is Easy Fancybox does not recognize content after the first page break and so it loads images without the light box.

Example: http://boyonamountain.com/?p=118&preview=1&_ppp=fe18270bb4

Now, I have been researching for hours now and it seems there are some work arounds with requiring a call back.

Problem is, I am a designer and this is my personal site so I only have HTML/CSS knowledge.

I found this: [how to bind fancybox to dynamic added element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081571/how-to-bind-fancybox-to-dynamic-added-element)

tried adding the code from that to the repeat template part of Ajax Load More,
I also tried to add it to the function.php, all to no avail.

Would someone be willing to help me trouble shoot this? Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using easy `fancybox` and you just have to bind an event to the `post-load` easy fancy box handler;
I chose the `focusin` event that really happens after the loading of my completed form :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).on( 'focusin', easy_fancybox_handler );
</script>
```

You have to tell the plugin that content is loaded, choosing the good event.

Comment: Put this script in the footer :) before the body closing markup